# What's the right way to allocate objects?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

How do you allocate an object?

Answers

```
a. MyClass *obj = malloc(sizeof(MyClass));
b. MyClass *obj = [MyClass alloc];
c. MyClass *obj = alloc(MyClass);
d. MyClass *obj = [MyClass new];
e. None of the above.
```

I'm thinking b or may be d. What do you think?

Comment: What's the tricky issue? I mean, something not documented in the Objective-C reference book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a. MyClass *obj = malloc(sizeof(MyClass));
```

This is just wrong. An objective-C object has a specific structure that malloc cannot make. This will NOT create a valid objective-C object.

```
b. MyClass *obj = [MyClass alloc];
```

This is the proper way to allocate an object. However all objective-c object must be passed some kind of -init message before it can be used.

```
c. MyClass *obj = alloc(MyClass);
```

No.

```
d. MyClass *obj = [MyClass new];
```

This is actually the same as [[MyClass alloc] init]. However since the user cannot choose which initializer to use when allocating the new object, most books recommending using the alloc/init method of creating a new object instead of this.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer E**

I almost never use `[MyClass alloc]` or `[MyClass new]`, but often `[[MyClass alloc] init]`.

**Quote by [Chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50742/chuck):**

> Originally in Objective-C, objects were created with new. As the OpenStep/Cocoa framework evolved, the designers developed the opinion that allocating the memory for an object and initializing its attributes were separate concerns and thus should be separate methods (for example, an object might be allocated in a specific memory zone). So the alloc-init style of object creation came into favor. Basically, new is old and almost-but-not-quite deprecated — thus you'll see that Cocoa classes have a lot of init methods but almost never any custom new methods.

Comment: `[MyClass new]` is essentially the same as calling `[[MyClass alloc] init]`

Comment: Indeed true, `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` and `[NSMutableArray new]` do for example exactly the same. Classes might however override the `new` implementation, using `[[MyClass alloc] init]` makes sure the object is allocated and initialized like expected (there are always exceptions of course).

Comment: Classes can override `alloc` as well, and the amount of classes overriding `alloc` is probably the same as classes overriding `new`.

Comment: Before ARC [[foo alloc] init] meant the new object was owned by the current context ([foo released] when foo wasn't necessary anymore), while [foo foo] was autoreleased. As of today, instance allocation became inconsistant with too many allocation patterns. There is no right pattern, and you cannot use only one with Cocoa (some classes have +classWithFoo: and no -initWithFoo:, or -initWithFoo: without +classWithFoo:).